# How to use QML_ELEMENT with cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qt5

The [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html) shows I can use QML_ELEMENT macro to create QML types from C++ by adding some variables in qmake's .pro file. But I'm using cmake

Comment: Did you try setting these as definition (prepocessor variable) with `target_compile_definitions`? Or maybe environment variable (but doubt that)

Comment: @Amfasis, no there is no such mention in docs

Comment: I don't see that much info in the docs about cmake, so I'm trying to think outside the docs (pun intended)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update (Qt 6.2+)

As of Qt 6.2, [qt_add_qml_module](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-6.2/qt-add-qml-module.html) is a single command for building qml modules that should take care of virtually everything, replacing amongst others the old `qt6_qml_type_registration` command.

#### Old answer (Qt 6.0/6.1)

Now that Qt 6.0 is out this is supported, albeit poorly documented. What you need now is:

```
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    QT_QML_MODULE_VERSION 1.0
    QT_QML_MODULE_URI     Foo
)

qt6_qml_type_registration(foo)
```

you can then do in qml:

```
import Foo
```

and you'll have access to types that have `QML_ELEMENT` and friends. Notes:

- Two files are created in the build output folder, `<project>_qmltyperegistrations.cpp` and `<project>.qmltypes`, if your imports are failing you can look at those to see which types are missing. I found that I needed to do full recompiles sometimes after adding/removing registered types.
- Qt examples have been migrated to cmake, so take a look at e.g. `Examples/Qt-6.0.0/quick/tableview/gameoflife` to see it in action
- There are now `pro2cmake.py` and `run_pro2cmake.py` files in the Qt sources at `Qt/6.0.0/Src/qtbase/util/cmake`. They are mentioned on this [Readme](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/dev/cmake) page, you can find them [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/dev/util/cmake), haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Qt6.2 removed the `qt6_qml_type_registration` and a more powerfull `qt_add_qml_module` should be used.

Comment: You also need to have `#include <QtQml>` otherwise `QML_ELEMENT` will not be recognised in the C++ declaration.

Comment: @Adverus Can you show an example on how to use qt_add_qml_module? the docs driving me crazy.

Answer (score 10):

### Edit (Qt 6.x)

This answer was originally posted for Qt 5.15. Now that Qt 6 is available, and if you are using Qt 6, refer to the [answer from @Adversus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530243/4223664).

### Original answer (Qt 5.x)

From what I can see, `CONFIG += qmltypes`, which is required to use `QML_ELEMENT`, is not yet supported in CMake by looking at the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html), even for the master branch.

And the efforts to provide a python .pro to cmake converter are for Qt6, not merged, and not functional as far as I can tell, by testing them from [util on the `wip/cmake` branch](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/util/cmake?h=wip/cmake) (the CMakeLists.txt didn't have relevant information).
You can see that the actual [conversion script](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/util/cmake/pro2cmake.py?h=wip/cmake) does test for `qmltypes` presence in CONFIG, but it doesn't seem to map to anything usable for CMake.

#### Solution

Instead of using `QML_ELEMENT` and `CONFIG += qmltypes`, which is brand new from Qt 5.15 (latest when writing this), and not supported at this time with CMake, use the good old [`qmlRegisterType`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) from C++:

```
#include "YouCustomCppClass.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Let you import it with "import ModuleName 1.0" on the QML side
    qmlRegisterType<YouCustomCppClass>("ModuleName", 1, 0, "YourQmlComponent");

    //Create your QML view or engine
}
```

This won't require anything specific on the project file side, as long as your code/plugin executes `qmlRegisterType` statement.

You can refer to Qt's documentation, same page as yours, but for Qt 5.14 instead of latest, which describes exactly that: [Writting QML extensions for C++ | Qt 5.14](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.14/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html)