# Qt6: Warnings when QML Listview accesses C++ model

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6

First of all, I'm new to Qt6 and QML, so maybe I am missing something obvious.

I'm trying to link a C++ model to a ListView in QML from a `QObject` property.
From [this doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) I should be able to use a `List<QObject*>` as a static model in a QML view.

However, in that example, the `QList<QObject*>` is passed directly to a `QQuickView`.
I would like to access the object list from a property of a `QObject` I can already access in QML.
But when I try to do that, nothing is shown in the list view, and I don't know what I am doing wrong...
Also, QML reports me a warning (see below my example code).

Here a working minimal example of what I am trying to achieve:

backend.h

```cpp
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>

// Contains the data I want to display for each element
class Item : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER m_name NOTIFY onNameChanged)

public:
    Item(QString name, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject{parent}, m_name(name)
    {}

signals:
    void onNameChanged();

private:
    QString m_name {"NULL"};
};

// This class contains the model I want to display.
// The data will be loaded before loading the QML file.
// It can be switched between a mockup and a real backend depending on the context.
class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString header MEMBER m_header NOTIFY onHeaderChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> model MEMBER m_model NOTIFY onModelChanged)

public:
    explicit Backend(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject{parent}
    {
        m_header = "Cpp Backend";
        m_model.append(new Item {"Cpp"});
        m_model.append(new Item {"backend"});
        m_model.append(new Item {"is"});
        m_model.append(new Item {"great!"});
    }

    virtual ~Backend() override
    {
        for (QObject* item : m_model)
            delete item;
    }

signals:
    void onHeaderChanged();
    void onModelChanged();

private:
    QString m_header;
    QList<QObject*> m_model;
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQMLContext>

#include "backend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Exposing the backend to QML with the name "cppBackend"
    Backend backend;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppBackend", &backend);

    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/TestBackend/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: mockupList
        ListElement { name: "Hello" }
        ListElement { name: "World!" }
        ListElement { name: "How" }
        ListElement { name: "are" }
        ListElement { name: "you?" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        spacing: 10
        orientation: ListView.Vertical

        //model: mockupList // this works as expected
        model: cppBackend.model // this doesn't show anything in the listview

        delegate: Item {
            id: myItem
            required property string name

            width: label.width
            height: label.height
            Text {
                id: label
                text: myItem.name
                font.pointSize: 24
            }
        }

        header: Text {
            width: parent.width
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pointSize: 48
            font.bold: true

            text: cppBackend.header // This works as expected
        }
    }
}
```

When I use te `mockupList` instead of the C++ backend, the items are displayed as expected.
However, when using the `cppBackend` I'm getting this warning:

```
qrc:/TestBackend/Main.qml:30:13: Required property name was not initialized qrc:/TestBackend/Main.qml: 30
```

It seems that the property `cppBackend.model` is accessed, but the items inside do not provide access to their properties as it seems it should to be done in the [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model)...

Comment: I'm looking into this. As a quick solution you could get rid of the required property and use `modelData.name` instead of `myItem.name`.

Comment: I tried your code and I was able to get it to work if I exposed the model to QML directly instead of accessing it as a property of the backend object. I don't actually know why that makes a difference.

Comment: @iam_peter I tried what you suggest and it works indeed, but I would rather avoid using `modelData` to be able to put the delegate in a separate file and test it alone.

Comment: @JarMan How did you achieved that? I would like that solution as a workaround, but I can't seem to make it works with a required property in the delegate. It works fine with `modelData` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made you an example that uses [`QML_SINGLETON`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_SINGLETON) to register the backend in QML and defines `DataObject` (`Item`) as a [`QML_ELEMENT`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#QML_ELEMENT) so it will be made visible in QML and the properties are being exposed.

I changed from `setContextProperty` to a singleton due to the reasons explained in this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/qt-qml-hot-tips-5-mike-trahearn/).

The important thing to make `DataObject` known in `Main.qml` is to import the URI of the module the `DataObject` sources were added to (`import Demo77967427`).

The only weird part is that without "casting" the `Backend.model` to a `list<DataObject>` it doesn't work.

```
property list<DataObject> myModel: Backend.model
```

And then continue to use `myModel` as the model that gets bound to the `ListView`.

**main.cpp**

```
...
qmlRegisterSingletonType<Backend>("FooBar", 1, 0, "Backend", [](QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *) {
    return new Backend();
});
...
```

**dataobject.h**

```
class DataObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER m_name NOTIFY nameChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    DataObject(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    DataObject(QString name, QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void nameChanged();

private:
    QString m_name;
};
```

**backend.h**

```
class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString header MEMBER m_header NOTIFY headerChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject *> model MEMBER m_model NOTIFY modelChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_SINGLETON

public:
    explicit Backend(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~Backend() override;

signals:
    void headerChanged();
    void modelChanged();

private:
    QString m_header;
    QList<QObject *> m_model;
};
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import FooBar
import Demo77967427

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property list<DataObject> myModel: Backend.model

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        spacing: 10
        orientation: ListView.Vertical

        model: root.myModel

        delegate: Item {
            id: myItem
            required property string name

            width: label.width
            height: label.height
            Text {
                id: label
                text: myItem.name
                font.pointSize: 24
            }
        }

        header: Text {
            width: parent.width
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pointSize: 48
            font.bold: true

            text: Backend.header
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the complete application [here](https://github.com/iam-peter/stackoverflow/tree/41df7a56b59c675221b6bf64134278f030a6603b/questions/77967427).

That said, the best way to expose models from C++ to QML is to derive from [`QAbstractListModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing).

---

You shouldn't prefix your notifier with `on`, have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-properties).

> Note: It is recommended that the NOTIFY signal be named
> <property>Changed where <property> is the name of the property. The
> associated property change signal handler generated by the QML engine
> will always take the form on<Property>Changed, regardless of the name
> of the related C++ signal, so it is recommended that the signal name
> follows this convention to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Thank you, it works great with the `QML_ELEMENT` and `QML_SINGLETON`! I didn't know about them... Thank you for your advises too!

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code in different ways, either by defining a global context property as suggested by **@JarMan** and as done in the documentation, or by using the `QVariant::fromValue` function while defining a `Q_INVOKABLE` function. However, I didn't really understand why the global one results in a `list<Item>`, while the other solutions result in a JS `Array`.

> *By printing the `model` inside the delegate, the type for `list<Item>` is `QQmlDMObjectData`, and for others, it is `QQmlDMListAccessorData`.*

Anyway, after **@iam_peter**'s answer, An idea crossed my mind. It reminded me of `QQmlListProperty` and its ease of conversion from a `QList<Object *>` (using [`QQmlListProperty(QObject *, QList<T *> *)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmllistproperty.html#QQmlListProperty-1)).

> *Note: [QQmlListProperty example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qtqml-referenceexamples-properties-example.html)*

So, I tried changing the property type to `QQmlListProperty`, and it worked. It actually doesn't need too many changes.

The changes are as follows:

```cpp
class Backend : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Item> model READ model)
public:
    QQmlListProperty<Item> model() {
        return {this, &m_model};
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
Item {
    Backend {
        id: back
    }

    ListView {
        model: back.model
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate: Label {
            required property string name
            text: name
        }
    }
}
```

*Final note*: As others have also suggested, it is best to use the [`QAbstractItemModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great too! I was doing something similar (a template list proxy) from scratch before iam_peter's answer. I didn't knew about `QQmlListProperty` neither! However, I prefer iam_peter's answer as it looks "cleaner" to expose my `Item` and `Backend` classes with `QML_ELEMENT` though.

Comment: @BenPyton You're welcome. Yes, using `QML_ELEMENT` is preferred, but I didn't have any plans to explain that, as it is a little unrelated to the main goal of the question. However, the way **@iam_peter** is used is imperfect. I suggest you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530243/11603485) post, which uses `qt_add_qml_module` in CMake to create a proper import name.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the model directly from QML works fine, even though accessing it through a Q_PROPERTY seems to fail for some reason. I don't understand the difference myself, but here is how I got it to work:

First create an accessor to get the model:

```
class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ...

    QList<QObject *> model() { return m_model; }
};
```

Then expose that model to QML:

```
Backend backend;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppBackendModel", QVariant::fromValue(backend.model()));
```

And finally access that model from QML.

```
    ListView {
        id: listView

        model: cppBackendModel

        delegate: Item {
            id: myItem
            required property string name
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you changed another thing too? When I try with only your changes, it does not work with the `required` property in the delegate. However, it does work when removing the required name property and replacing with `modelData.item`.

Comment: After some tests, it seems the real issue comes from the `required` property in the delegate. It works fine also when I replace the required property by `property string name: modelData.name` (with either `cppBackend.model` or your `cppBackendModel`).
With that change, I can put the delegate in its own file `MyListItem` with a default value for the name, and then put in the list view delegate `MyListItem { name: modelData.name }`.
But it still doesn't work when I write `MyListItem { required name }`.

Comment: When I run it, I still use the required property and it works correctly. I am testing with Qt 6.5.3, if that matters.