# QML ListView delegate that works for both QML and C++ models

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6

I'm asking this question after getting some insights on [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77967427/qt6-warnings-when-qml-listview-accesses-c-model) on displaying C++ backend model in QML.

I am new to Qt6 and QML, and I think I understood how to link models to delegates in QML, but maybe I missed something...

I would like to have a QML `ListView` delegate that works for both a QML list model and a C++ list model.
This requirement is needed to be able to have the designers to work in Qt Design Studio with a QML model mockup, to have a C++ mockup for unit tests, and to have the real C++ model loaded from the backend.

However, QML and C++ models seem to be accessed differently in the QML `ListView` delegate:

- C++ model item properties are accessed through `modelData.propertyName`
- QML model item properties are accessed through `required propertyName` (for an existing property in the delegate)

**My question**: is there an unified way to access properties for both C++ and QML models?

Here is a minimal working example to demonstrate my issue (see `Main.qml` for the difference between QML and C++ access):

backend.h

```cpp
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <QObject>

// Contains the data I want to display for each element
class Item : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER m_name NOTIFY onNameChanged)

public:
    Item(QString name, QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject{parent}, m_name(name)
    {}

signals:
    void onNameChanged();

private:
    QString m_name {"NULL"};
};

// This class contains the model to display in the ListView.
// The data will be loaded before loading the QML file.
class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Item*> model MEMBER m_model NOTIFY onModelChanged)

public:
    explicit Backend(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject{parent}
    {
        m_model.append(new Item {"Cpp"});
        m_model.append(new Item {"backend"});
        m_model.append(new Item {"is"});
        m_model.append(new Item {"great!"});
    }

    virtual ~Backend() override
    {
        for (Item* item : m_model)
            delete item;
    }

signals:
    void onModelChanged();

private:
    QList<Item*> m_model;
};

#endif // BACKEND_H
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQMLContext>

#include "backend.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Exposing the backend to QML with the name "cppBackend"
    Backend backend;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppBackend", &backend);

    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/TestBackend/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

MyListItem.qml

```
import QtQuick

Item {
    id: myItem
    property string name: "Default Name"

    width: label.width
    height: label.height
    Text {
        id: label
        text: myItem.name
        font.pointSize: 24
    }
}
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: mockupList
        ListElement { name: "Hello" }
        ListElement { name: "World!" }
        ListElement { name: "How" }
        ListElement { name: "are" }
        ListElement { name: "you?" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        spacing: 10
        orientation: ListView.Vertical

        model: mockupList // Works only with 'required name'
        //model: cppBackend.model // Works only with 'name: modelData.name'

        delegate: MyListItem {
            required name // Works only with QML list model
            //name: modelData.name // Works only with C++ list model
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results I get when commenting in/out the `model` and `name` lines in the `Main.qml` file:

- ✔ `mockupList` with `required name`: QML model items are properly displayed
- ✘ `mockupList` with `name: modelData.name`: all items show the default name in `MyListItem.qml`
- ✘ `cppBackend.model` with `required name`: No item was created and throws the warning `Required property name was not initialized`
- ✔ `cppBackend.model` with `name: modelData.name`: C++ model items are properly displayed

Comment: I wanted to comment that on your last question already. The "best" way of defining a model for both C++ and QML is to derive from `QAbstractItemModel` or its derivatives. This way you can define the roles you want. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractlistmodel.html#subclassing

Comment: I agree with iam_peter. QList is easy, but, it is similar to a Javascript array. Like a Javascript array, you will need to use modelData to access it in your delegates. If you want a true model experience, consider QAbstractItemModel, QAbstractListModel, QQmlListProperty instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @iam_peter in [my linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77967427/qt6-warnings-when-qml-listview-accesses-c-model) solved this question too.

**TL;DR**:
There was 3 elements missing in my example code:

- Add `QML_ELEMENT` in `Item` class.
- Add `import TestBackend` (the URI of the project defined in the CMake file) in `Main.qml`
- Use a property in `Main.qml` to store the backend model outside the list view like that:

```
Window {
    id: root
    // ...
    property list<Item> itemList: cppBackend.model
    ListView {
        // ...
        model: root.itemList
        // ...
    }
}
```

With these minimal changes to my example code, both the QML model and the C++ model can be accessed with the delegate's `required name` line in `Main.qml`.

### **EDIT:**

The answer of @smr on my linked question solves also this question and requires even less code changes.
The only change to the example code is to replace the `Q_PROPERTY` of the model by `QQmlListProperty<Item>` like that:

```cpp
class Backend : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Item> model READ model NOTIFY onModelChanged)
public:
    // ...
    QQmlListProperty<Item> model() { return {this, &m_model}; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need to cast the `model` to `list<Item>` in QML side. I explained in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77976862/11603485).

Comment: @smr Thank you very much! I've edited my answer here to add your solution too!

Comment: `QQmlListProperty` is not a proper model. It is not an issue if you don't add or remove elements from it.